# mappers stuck at 2 % in simple hive insert command

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to run an insert command which inner joins 2 tables with data in one table as 34567892 and another table is 6754289. The issue is , the mappers are not getting started after completing 2%. I have used various properties like set tez.am.resource.memory.mb=16384;
set hive.tez.container.size=16384;
set hive.tez.java.opts=-Xms13107m;
but still no luck.
Can someone please help me to figure out what to do?

Comment: please share table structure and their unique key and SQL. It  may happen your tables are cross joined or not joining on unique key or stats arent gathered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through researching a lot, I have found the following properties helpful and which ran my query in 2-3 minutes:

- set hive.auto.convert.join = false;
- set hive.exec.parallel=true;
- set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
- set hive.exec.parallel=true;
- set hive.cbo.enable=true;
- set hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
- set hive.stats.fetch.column.stats=true;
- set hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats=true;